# How can I display a message when someone updates to a new version of my extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have seen extensions display an important notification in the bottom right when vscode auto-dates them, like this:

[image: eg]

How can I display a message like this the **first** time someone runs the new version of an extension I maintain?

Comment: in the extensions that do this look in the source code for the `showInformationMessage` call and find out when it is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked at the source code of the `Material Theme` how they do it. It was the first extension to show me such a message and a theme extension would not have a lot of code.

What they do is: write a file in the directory of the extension that contains the version number of the extension the last time they showed the message. It is stored in JSON format because `package.json` is too.

On activation:

- search for the file `user_config.json` in the extension directory (place where `package.json` is)
- if not found => show message
- read version numbers stored in file `user_config.json` and `package.json`
- compare if `package.json` version is bigger (major - minor - patch)
- if bigger => show message
- if message shown => save `package.json` version in `user_config.json`

Comment: Ah, good call, figured it might be just writing the prev version to a flat file. Tx for pointing to that Material Theme extension, btw. Pretty good template for this here: https://github.com/material-theme/vsc-material-theme/blob/596b6e68a95b13c1809e16db7f89b0491f48f804/src/core/extension-manager.ts#L88

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vscode.window.showInformationMessage` API, to show buttons you can pass as many arguments you want after 1st one, which is `title`

```js
const resp = await vscode.window.showInformationMessage(
  "There are multiple formatters for 'JSON' files...",
  "Configure..."
);

if (resp === "Configure...") {
  //your logic here
}
```

Comment: the question is how to find out in the activate function that it is the **first** activate after an update of the extension

Comment: Right this is the correct API to show the message. I worded the question poorly -- really what I wanted to do was understand when the version number changed (on extension upgrade)